# llvm - Cannot reproduce Hello World Pass

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am new to LLVM, and I was trying to reproduce the Hello World pass example in http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#quickstart . The pass compiles just fine; however I cannot reproduce the output given in the documentation.

Instead of getting

Hello: __main
Hello: puts
Hello: main

I am simply getting

Hello: main

It's like the pass only goes through the user-defined main function. Is there a flag that I should turn on for the pass to print the complete function trace?

Thank you.

P.S. I am using version 3.1 of LLVM

Comment: Can you see all 3 functions when you do `llvm-dis -o - hello.bc`?

Comment: @Oak Yes. Here is the output: `; ModuleID = 'hello.bc'
target datalayout = "e-p:32:32:32-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:32:64-f32:32:32-f64:32:64-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-f80:32:32-n8:16:32-S128"
target triple = "i386-pc-linux-gnu"

@str = private unnamed_addr constant [12 x i8] c"hello world\00"

define i32 @main() nounwind {
entry:
  %puts = tail call i32 @puts(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([12 x i8]* @str, i32 0, i32 0))
  ret i32 0
}

declare i32 @puts(i8* nocapture) nounwind`

Comment: There's only one function there (`define i32 @main()`), which is why your pass only printed one function. Your pass works fine; the only question is why the `hello.bc` file doesn't include all 3 functions as expected by the documentations.

Comment: @Oak I see. I don't know why that's happening, though. I followed the installation guide exactly. Should I post a new thread for that question?

Comment: I don't know, your call. I'm just saying your pass is fine :)